# auto complete in jquery with different display text

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, auto-populate

I am trying the following autocomplete logic. but its not working. my desired output is the display text and the value that is being sent should be different(example Cricket should be sent as cri.)

here is the markup:

```
<div id="main">
<p>
<a href="http://www.justwebcode.com" rel="index,follow">Just Web Code (www.justwebcode.com)</a>
</p>
&nbsp;Enter any Sport Name: <input type="text" id="autocomplete" />
</div>
```

and the jquery is:

```
$(function(){


 var games = [
   { value: 'cricket', data: 'cri' },

   { value: 'chess', data: 'che' }
]; 

$("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
source: {games.value ;games.data}
});

});
```

Comment: To get things clear, You want to show your objects value at your suggestion list, but when an item is selected, you want to post the data attribute of your object, right?

Answer (score 0):

Please check [JQuery documentation for Autocomplete](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source)

It says, that `source` can be

> An array of objects with label and value properties: [ {
>   label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]